# Value changes when passing that value to a function?

Tags: c++, math

When I debug this program, I see that max is a garbage number instead of the value I pass to it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

float findPrimes(int max) {

    float* primes = new float[max];

    bool* boolarray = new bool[max];
    for(int i=0; i<=max; i++) {
        boolarray[i] = true;
    }

    int x = 1;

    for(int i=2; i<=sqrt(max); i++) {
        if(boolarray[i]) {
            for(int j=pow(i, 2)+x*i; j<=max; x++)
            {
                boolarray[j] = false;
            }
        }
    }

    int n = 0;

    while(n<=max) {
        if(boolarray[n]) 
            primes[n] = boolarray[n];
        n++;
    }

    return primes[max];

}

int main() {

    float answer = findPrimes(6);

    printf("%f\n", answer);

    _sleep(10000);

    return 0;
}
```

It is telling me that max is a junk number when I debug it, so that's why the program doesn't execute (it runs, but nothing happens). I'm pretty sure I'm doing all the math right (using the Sieve of Eratosthenes), so what gives?

---

Edited:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

float findPrimes(int max) {

    std::cout << max << "\n";

    float* primes = new float[max-1];

    bool* boolarray = new bool[max-1];
    for(int i=0; i<=max-1; i++) {
        boolarray[i] = true;
    }

    int x = 1;

    for(int i=2; i<=sqrt(max); i++) {
        if(boolarray[i]) {
            for(int j=pow(i, 2)+x*i; j<=max-1; x++)
            {
                boolarray[j] = false;
            }
        }
    }

    int n = 0;

    while(n<=max-1) {
        if(boolarray[n]) 
            primes[n] = boolarray[n];
        n++;
    }

    return primes[max-2];

}

int main() {

    printf("%f\n", findPrimes(6));

    _sleep(10000);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `i<=max` means that `boolarray[i]` will run when `i == max` which goes out of bounds and is UB. Same thing for `while (n<=max)`

Comment: Are you sure?  If you do `cout << max << "\n"` as the very first line in the function, is it junk?

Comment: Are you compiling in release mode?

Comment: Ok, I've set the first initializations of the arrays to [max-1]. It's still not showing anything when I output, however when I set it to print what max was, that worked, so max isn't the problem.

Comment: Seth, what do you mean?

Comment: @Tetramputechture you have to use @ before the person's name to notify them, I just happened to check on this question or I wouldn't have seen your reply. Anyway, I mean that the array's size is `max`, so the maximum valid index is `max - 1`. And you're going all the way up to `max`, which is one past the end of the array, accessing which is UB.

Comment: @SethCarnegie I posted my edited code. Now the function returns -0.000000. I'll run it through a debugger to see what's happening.

Comment: `primes[max]` is not set to anything [and outside the range by two].

Answer (score 1):

You access out of range.

```
bool* boolarray = new bool[max-1];
for(int i=0; i<=max-1; i++) {
    boolarray[i] = true;
}
```

Let's say max is 5. The first line allocates 4 bools, numbered 0 to 3. The loop loops from 0 to 4. But there is no entry 4. There are only 4 entries, 0, 1, 2, and 3.

You should probably do this:

```
bool* boolarray = new bool[max];
for(int i=0; i<max; i++) {
    boolarray[i] = true;
}
```

Now, if max is 5, you allocate 5 bools, numbered 0 to 4. Your loop now goes from 0 to 4, which is what you want.

Comment: Ok, I fixed that, now it just returns 1 =\ this is so frustrating! I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, it all makes sense in my head.

Comment: Add lots of logging so you can see where it first differs from what you expect. Why are you using `float`s?! Why are you using `pow`? Also, this for loop `for(int j=pow(i, 2)+x*i; j<=max-1; x++)` makes no sense. The loop variable is `j`, yet you don't change `j` in the loop!

Comment: @DavidScwartz I do change j in the loop, by incrementing x. Or do I need to put (j=pow(i, 2)+(++x*i) instead of just x++?
This is the Sieve of Eratosthenes, by the way, I forgot if I had mentioned that.

Comment: @Tetramputechture: Incrementing `x` has no effect on `j`. They're two different variables.